# A* Pathfinding is not working in a 3D Minecraft Environment

Tags: c#, 3d, minecraft, path-finding, a-star

Quite a long time ago I tried implementing a Minecraft Bot with pathfinding using a modified client and a simple breadth first search algorithm which worked, but was extremely imperformant. Nevertheless I actually got it as far as being able to decide whether it might even be more intelligent to break certain blocks or place them to get to its goal.

So I started implementing my own Minecraft Client, which works 'OK' I guess :D Also I wanted to use A* Pathfinding for better performance. Unfortunately after implementing it I started to see that it worked great in most cases, but as soon as the path got more complicated it would just calculate for minutes straight without finding a path to the goal. It seems like it either searches in the wrong direction or skips the goal entirely somehow. Either way, it doesn't find it. In addition to that after implementing jumping to be able to jump over gaps it would just keep jumping no matter if he had to or not. Looks like a happy Minecraft player jumping around, but doesn't make any sense. Even after setting the cost of jumping to an extremely large number, it would keep jumping everywhere instead of walking normally.

I've started thinking there must be a fundamental error in this approach but couldn't find out what it might be.

This is my pathfinding logic

```
class PathFinder
{
    private const int WalkCost = 10;
    private const int DiagonalWalkCost = 14;
    private const int JumpCost = 5;

    private const int MaxDistance = 100;

    private int GetDistance(Node a, Node b)
    {
        return Math.Abs(b.X - a.X) + Math.Abs(b.Y - a.Y) + Math.Abs(b.Z - a.Z);
    }

    public Path FindPath(Node start, Node goal)
    {
        start.H = GetDistance(start, goal) * WalkCost;
        var open = new List<Node>();
        open.Add(start);
        var closed = new List<Node>();
        var cameFrom = new Dictionary<Node, Node>();
        var action = new Dictionary<Node, Movement>();
        var done = false;
        var considered = 0;
        var world = Client.Instance.World;

        Node current;
        while (open.Count > 0)
        {
            current = open.OrderBy(n => n.F).First();

            open.Remove(current);
            closed.Add(current);

            if (current == goal)
            {
                done = true;
                break;
            }

            foreach (var neighbour in GetNeighbours(current))
            {
                if (GetDistance(neighbour, start) > MaxDistance)
                    continue;

                if (closed.Contains(neighbour))
                    continue;

                if (neighbour.Y > current.Y) //Jump up
                {
                    if (!IsWalkable(neighbour)
                        || world.IsSolid(current.Up().Up()))
                        continue;

                    neighbour.G = current.G + WalkCost + JumpCost;
                    action[neighbour] = Movement.JumpUp;
                }
                else if(neighbour.Y < current.Y) //Jump Down
                {
                    if (!IsWalkable(neighbour)
                        || world.IsSolid(neighbour.Up().Up()))
                        continue;

                    neighbour.G = current.G + WalkCost + JumpCost;
                    action[neighbour] = Movement.Fall;
                }
                else //Walk
                {
                    if (!IsWalkable(neighbour))
                        continue;

                    if (neighbour.X != current.X && neighbour.Z != current.Z) //Diagonal
                    {
                        if (world.IsSolid(new Node(neighbour.X, current.Y, current.Z))
                            || world.IsSolid(new Node(neighbour.X, current.Y, current.Z).Up())
                            || world.IsSolid(new Node(current.X, current.Y, neighbour.Z))
                            || world.IsSolid(new Node(current.X, current.Y, neighbour.Z).Up()))
                            continue;

                        neighbour.G = current.G + DiagonalWalkCost;
                        action[neighbour] = Movement.Walk;
                    }
                    else //Straight
                    {
                        if(GetDistance(current, neighbour) >= 2) //Straight Jump
                        {
                            var nodeBetween = new Node(current.X + (neighbour.X - current.X) / 2, current.Y, current.Z + (neighbour.Z - current.Z) / 2);
                            if (world.IsSolid(current.Up().Up())
                                || world.IsSolid(neighbour.Up().Up())
                                || world.IsSolid(nodeBetween)
                                || world.IsSolid(nodeBetween.Up())
                                || world.IsSolid(nodeBetween.Up().Up()))
                                continue;

                            neighbour.G = current.G + 2 * WalkCost + JumpCost;
                            action[neighbour] = Movement.JumpGap;
                        }
                        else //Straight Walk
                        {
                            neighbour.G = current.G + WalkCost;
                            action[neighbour] = Movement.Walk;
                        }
                    }
                }

                considered++;

                var previousEntry = open.FirstOrDefault(n => n == neighbour);
                if (previousEntry == null || neighbour.G < previousEntry.G)
                {
                    neighbour.H = GetDistance(neighbour, goal) * WalkCost;
                    cameFrom[neighbour] = current;
                    open.Add(neighbour);
                }
            }
        }

        Client.Instance.SendChatMessage(String.Format("{0} possible moves considered", considered));

        if (!done)
            return null;

        var currentNode = goal;
        var path = new List<Node>();
        var moves = new List<Movement>();
        while (currentNode != start)
        {
            path.Add(currentNode);
            moves.Add(action[action.Keys.First(k => k == currentNode)]);
            currentNode = cameFrom[cameFrom.Keys.First(k => k == currentNode)];
        }
        path.Add(start);
        path.Reverse();
        moves.Add(Movement.Walk);
        moves.Reverse();
        return new Path(path, moves);
    }

    private bool IsWalkable(Node node)
    {
        var world = Client.Instance.World;
        var block = world.GetBlock(node.X, node.Y, node.Z);
        return world.IsSolid(node.Down())
            && !world.IsSolid(node)
            && !world.IsSolid(node.Up())
            && !block.BlockName.Contains("water")
            && !block.BlockName.Contains("lava");
    }

    private Node[] GetNeighbours(Node node)
    {
        var neighbours = new List<Node>();

        //neighbours.Add(node.Up()); //pillar up
        //neighbours.Add(node.Down()); //dig down

        neighbours.Add(node.North()); //simple walk
        neighbours.Add(node.East());
        neighbours.Add(node.South());
        neighbours.Add(node.West());

        neighbours.Add(node.North().East()); //diagonal walk
        neighbours.Add(node.North().West());
        neighbours.Add(node.South().East());
        neighbours.Add(node.South().West());

        neighbours.Add(node.North().Up()); //jump up
        neighbours.Add(node.East().Up());
        neighbours.Add(node.South().Up());
        neighbours.Add(node.West().Up());

        neighbours.Add(node.North().Down()); //fall down
        neighbours.Add(node.East().Down());
        neighbours.Add(node.South().Down());
        neighbours.Add(node.West().Down());

        neighbours.Add(node.North().North()); //jump 1 wide gap
        neighbours.Add(node.East().East());
        neighbours.Add(node.South().South());
        neighbours.Add(node.West().West());

        return neighbours.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And this is my Node class

```
public class Node/* : IEquatable<Node>*/
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public int G { get; set; }
    public int H { get; set; }

    public int F { get => G + H; }

    public Node CameFrom { get; set; }

    public Node(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public Node()
    {

    }

    public Node Down()
    {
        return new Node(X, Y - 1, Z);
    }

    public Node Up()
    {
        return new Node(X, Y + 1, Z);
    }

    public Node East()
    {
        return new Node(X + 1, Y, Z);
    }

    public Node West()
    {
        return new Node(X - 1, Y, Z);
    }

    public Node South()
    {
        return new Node(X, Y, Z + 1);
    }
    public Node North()
    {
        return new Node(X, Y, Z - 1);
    }

    //public bool Equals(Node other)
    //{
    //    return other.X == X && other.Y == Y && other.Z == Z;
    //}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Node))
            return false;

        return this == (Node)obj;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Node a, Node b)
    {
        if (a is null && b is object || b is null && a is object)
            return false;
        if (a is null && b is null)
            return true;
        return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y && a.Z == b.Z;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Node a, Node b)
    {
        if (a is null && b is object || b is null && a is object)
            return true;
        if (a is null && b is null)
            return false;

        return a.X != b.X || a.Y != b.Y || a.Z != b.Z;
    }

    //public static bool operator ==(Node a, Node b)
    //{
    //    return a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode();
    //}

    //public static bool operator !=(Node a, Node b)
    //{
    //    return a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode();
    //}

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + X.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Y.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Z.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Ignore the chaotic equality checks. I was thinking it might have to do with the way I check equality in nodes but had no success with that either, besides my code being messier than it was before xD

Does anybody have any suggestions on what might be the problem here ? Any articles on something similar, that means pathfinding in a 3D environment with jumping over gaps, would be greatly appreciated aswell.

**Addition**

This is a visualization of what a run looks like that took 16.5sec, 62.700 possible neighbours looked at and eventually a path of 48 moves total.

The bot was trying to go from the orange block on the right, to the blue block at the end of this ladder kind of thing, which is in the air, which makes it harder for pathfinding to be fair:

[image]

This is the visualization:

[image]

Green: Path taken, Blue: Closed List, Light Blue: Open List

From what I can see, the pathfinding seems to be working, but my uneducated assumption would be, that it is quite ineffective as it had a lot of blocks in the closed list before finding the goal eventually.

This time seems to increase exponentially with longer paths, as it takes up to half an hour or so to find the goal sometimes, which I would consider as not working.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen all the code but the GetDistance seems wrong.
Let's say that we forget Y.
(1,1) and (2,2) would have a distance of 2 with your method so the same distance as (1,1) and (1,3) which is wrong, you can make a draw to see that.

For a 3D distance the calcul is

```
float deltaX = b.x - a.x;
float deltaY = b.y - a.y;
float deltaZ = b.z - a.z;

float distance = (float) Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
```

Comment: Damn, that might just be the only thing I haven't thought about. I will try that out, when I get back from work, but it looks like that might be my issue

Comment: I have implemented the Euclidian distance formula now and from what I can see, this might have been a problem, that contributed to the pathfinding not working. But apperently not my only one, as it still takes up to or even more than 5 minutes for some difficult cases, which can't be correct :/

Answer (score 1):

Another try:
What you can try to improve performance:

- Since you already implented get HashCode, you can change the list in HastSet, especially closed because you are using contains on it and with List it's in O(n), with HashSet in O(1)
- The OrderBy.First() is not the best way to do it because it has to sort the list which also takes a lot of time. Maybe you can do the same thing with Min() and Select()

Can you do that and tell me if it works better ? I tried on my computer and it seems to work.[image]

Comment: I have implemented your changes now, and I think that definetely made a difference. But for some reason it still doesn't find the goal under certain circumstances, or just takes extremely long, and by that I mean minutes. When it finds it on the other hand, it's done in somewhere between 10 and 500ms or so. In terms of performance theres a lot I have to improve, but I am not sure whether it's a mistake in the pathfinding that is causing it to take exponentially longer or something else. I have also removed the neighbours for jumping, that improved it, but still it doesn't work 100% reliably

Comment: Humm yeah if most query take between 10 and 500ms it might not be a performance problem, Have you tried to visualize which cells were opened like the black shape on my image ? it might give you  a clue. I guess you have already checked that but maybe the path is unreachable or the distance between start and end is above MaxDistance ?

Comment: I have thought about visualizing it, but didn't quite know how to do it properly. May I ask how you created you graphic ? I'll try that out then and report my results.

At the moment I have a different issue to fix though. The way I am receiving the data from the server is so slow, that it takes like 5 tries for it to connect without timing out. Adding more packets made it too slow now. It's code that I created years ago, so it's quite bad but i honestly don't know how I would do that better. I mostly do ERP-Systems and similar at work, so performance was never my strength :D

Comment: I did it in wpf with canvas and rectangle, you can probably do it with any language. I am just printing it at the end so not in real time.I set the width of rectangle at 5 and the position is (5*x, 5*z) so I don't visualize the y axe it would probably be  harder

Comment: I edited my original question with some pictures, that should show everything necessary

Comment: As I don't expect any more answers to come in I am just going to hand you the bounty, as you obvioulsy put a lot of afford into helping me, so you definetely deserve it. In case you are interested, I would love get in contact with you, as I think I could learn a lot from you in terms of performance optimization and similiar. Also it would be interesting having a closer look into the code together, to maybe find other things that could be causing problems :)

Comment: Wow thanks, I don' know if I will be able to help you since I am not that good and I have not a lot of free time but here's my mail: pmiche04@gmail.com if you can send me the same example but without having to use minecraft I will be able to debug it, but I don't know how much time it would take you to do that without minecraft. Since the world variable is probably coming from a dll or an api or something